# Please, do NOT upvote unclear, opinion-based and too broad questions

Tags: discussion, voting

I've noticed that the community keeps upvoting questions that are either

1. not fully clear to be properly answered
2. opinion-based
3. too broad

Please, don't upvote this type of question/post, even if you find them interesting. Voting is our way of evaluating the quality of the post, both in terms of "interestingness" (which is subjective, of course), but, **more importantly**, in terms of the points mentioned above, whether it's on-topic or not, and, in the case of answers, whether they are correct or not.

I remind you that our site is about **Artificial Intelligence**, so it's **not just** about machine learning, and **it is not** about statistics or data science, although theoretical ML questions are, of course, on-topic here too. Our site is also about **artificial general intelligence**, **evolutionary algorithms**, **computational learning theory**, **affective computing**, **search** and **philosophy of AI**.

Examples of posts that have been unreasonably upvoted recently

1. [How real was the movie Ex Machina (2014)?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/33986/2444) (this will lead to opinions, which is **not** suitable for our site!)
2. [Is my intuition about RNN wrong?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/33995/2444) is unclear: there are not enough details to answer this question: why did you upvote this? I am not saying it should be downvoted, but it should also not be upvoted, as some details are missing in order to provide an answer.
3. https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/34002/2444 could be too broad: it's not clear whether the OP is familiar with backpropagation or not. What kind of answer is the OP looking for? Do they want us to write a 5-page post explaining how backpropagation works?

Here are **my** rules of thumb on how to vote

1. If you don't know what's being asked, don't upvote, even if you think the question is interesting, in some sense
2. Don't upvote a question only because you don't know the answer but you don't even fully understand what's being asked
3. If a question can be answered easily with a google search, don't upvote, unless it's a fundamental question for AI that could benefit our site.
4. If there is no evidence of research effort before asking the question, don't upvote (actually, you may consider downvoting)
5. If a post/question doesn't provide enough details or is not fully clear, downvote (or, at least, don't upvote, and maybe ask for clarification)
6. Don't upvote off-topic questions.
7. Downvote opinion-based questions. ([Our site was created under the "science" category!](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence))
8. Don't upvote posts that contain multiple questions or the only question is too broad (requires a lot of effort to be answered properly). Ask the OP to ask the questions in separate posts or to be more specific about the question or type of answer he's looking for.
9. Upvote questions that are **fundamentally** important for **Artificial Intelligence** (and, at the same time, are clear, not opinion-based, or too broad)
10. If you don't know if an answer is correct or not, don't vote (a highly upvoted answer that is wrong can be very misleading and even harmful).
11. If an answer is (even partially) wrong, downvote.
12. If an answer does not even partially address the actual question (and contains unnecessary or unrelated details), downvote.

I know that voting is a little bit subjective, but it's important to vote "correctly" in order for the good content to be at the top of the site and the bad content to be at the bottom.

**NOTE**: this has nothing to do with being nice. You should not upvote or you should not be afraid of downvoting because you want to be nice. Here's an analogy: would you give a 10/10 to a student, even if their solution is wrong or not appropriate? No. You shouldn't do that only because you want to be nice. It's not your fault if the student didn't study enough or didn't prepare itself for the exam/exercise. Do we want bad students to be our doctors? Would you put the fate of your health/life in the hands of an irresponsible and careless person? I don't think so.